# jQuery .html disappears on function exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm doing some validation on a field. I'm first running an Ajax GET to trigger an MVC action result, which will find out if the field is valid. I'm then using .addClass and .html to set a validation message above the field. What's happening is that the validation message is showing up right after the .html, but it disappears once the ending curly brace is passed (i.e. the function exits).

Why would an ending curly brace cause my validation message to go away?

Here is my code:

**Field Initialization (at the top of the .js file)**:

```
var $postalCode = $("#AccountBaseModel\\.Person\\.PostalCode");
```

**In HTML:**

```
                <div class="content-block__fourth-column">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AccountBaseModel.Person.PostalCode)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.AccountBaseModel.Person.PostalCode)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AccountBaseModel.Person.PostalCode, new { id = "AccountBaseModel.Person.PostalCode", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
```

**Main Function ($form.Submit):**

```
$form.submit(function () {
    //if not all the fields are entered (or the datestring is totally invalid) set it back to empty to cause validation
    if ($date.val().match(dateRegEx) == null) {
        $date.val("");
    }

    var usPostalValid = true;
    var caPostalValid = true;

    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
    if ($postalCode != null) {
        $.get('/api/NCP/ValidatePostalCode', { postalCode: $postalCode.val() }, function (data) {
            if (data.invalidUSPostal) {
                usPostalValid = false;
            }
            if (data.invalidCAPostal) {
                caPostalValid = false;
            }
        });
    }
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ async: true });

    clearErrorMessage($postalCode);
    if (!usPostalValid) {
        showErrorMessage($postalCode, 'Invalid US postal code.');
        $form.data("isValid", false);
    } else if (!caPostalValid) {
        showErrorMessage($postalCode, 'Invalid CA postal code.');
        $form.data("isValid", false);
    } else {
        $form.data("isValid", true);
    }


    //manually validate date and file field (because hidden)
    var dateValid = $date.valid();
    var promoCheck = checkDatePromo($form, $date, $year, $month, $day, $promoDateTime);
    var fileValid = $file.valid();
    return dateValid && promoCheck && fileValid && $form.valid() && (usPostalValid && caPostalValid);
});
```

**clearErrorMessage():**

```
function clearErrorMessage(element) {
   var id = $(element).attr('id');
   if (id.indexOf("ShippingPageModel") == 0) {
    id = id.replace('_', '.');
   }
   $(element).closest('.form-group').find("span[data-valmsg-for='" + id + "']").removeClass('field-validation-error').addClass('field-validation-valid').html('');
}
```

**showErrorMessage():**

```
function showErrorMessage(element, message) {
   var id = $(element).attr('id');
   if (id.indexOf("ShippingPageModel") == 0) {
    id = id.replace('_', '.');
   }

   var validationElement = $(element).closest('.form-group').find("span[data-valmsg-for='" + id + "']");

   validationElement.removeClass('field-validation-valid').addClass('field-validation-error').html(message);
} // Once this line is finished executing, the validation message is gone..
```

Comment: Where is '$postalCode' coming from?

Comment: Are these 'Person' and PostalCode class names? $("#AccountBaseModel\\.Person\\.PostalCode"); If they are why are u escaping them? It will possible for you to post your HTML here please

Comment: AccountBaseModel and Person are attributes of model classes. I am escaping because the ID I set has periods and jQuery requires you to escape those. I put in that ID because the showErrorMessage would not work otherwise. It does a match on ID, and for some reason it had to have periods.. I added the full HTML for the postal code field.

Comment: Ok, so I suppose when you (console.log($postalCode)  you got  the correct value. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, in the f12 dev tools, I added a watch for $postalCode and it has the correct value.

Comment: I see you are using a template for your HTML, so I can not see if the postalCode is an input value or just a text string in the element. Can you tell me about this? I hope this makes sense for you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. It's a TextBoxFor - check my html. It's going to be a string. What else do you need to know?

Comment: I am trying to check your code and I have to do it 'top down'. So if $postalCode is a string and not an input value you can not reference it so: $postalCode.val() but you have to do this $postalCode.text() instead.

Comment: What is your submit action? What happens after this event handler finishes? My assumption would be it posts to the server, which would cause a refresh, no? unless your conditional comes out false of course.

Comment: In other words, .html() doesn't just magically unhappen. Something is either re-modifying it, or your page is refreshing. Figure out which is happening.

Comment: @KevinB The very last line of the main function returns true or false depending on the variables involved, depending on if the element is valid. So in my case, caPostalValid was false, so it didn't postback. No refresh happens.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't postback? what are you using to test that? Like i said, .html() doesn't just magically get undone. it can't.

Comment: @KevinB I'm sure it didn't postback. I have a breakpoint on the HttpPost action result for the page. And I am debugging the JS. It never posts back to the C# code.

Comment: What else could be removing the message? Add a breakpoint to that method (the clearErrorMessage method)

Comment: @KevinB I am not skipping over anything. The JS executes the last line of the function, and the validation label shows. Once it executes the closing brace, it is gone. Nothing else is run. I will try to get a video up soon so you can see for yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98382/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-paul).